# Oracle - rewrite the trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm getting an error ORA-04091 (Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.) every time I run a trigger.

Here is the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER comment_date_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "comment"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  date_article TIMESTAMP;
  date_parent TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW."comment_parent_id" IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT "comment_date" INTO date_parent FROM "comment_view" WHERE "comment_id" = :NEW."comment_parent_id";
    END IF;
    SELECT "article_date" INTO date_article FROM "article" WHERE "article_id" = :NEW."comment_article_id";
    IF :NEW."comment_date" > SYSTIMESTAMP THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, '...');
    ELSIF :NEW."comment_date" < date_article THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, '...');
    ELSIF :NEW."comment_date" < date_parent THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20006, '...');
    END IF;
END;
```

What's the easiest solution to solve this problem, please? As you could see, I tried to use a view, but the problem remains.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you change *before insert or update* to *after insert or update*? It should be the same effect, since you don't intend to change any :new. values, and you'll end up rolling back the transaction if it fails validation.

Comment: It's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute a query on the same table of the trigger because the table is being modified.

Only workaround I know is to declare the trigger with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`: this will unlink the transaction that triggered the trigger from the queries executed by the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER comment_date_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON comment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

    date_article TIMESTAMP;
    date_parent TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    IF :NEW.comment_parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT comment_date INTO date_parent FROM comment_view WHERE comment_id = :NEW.comment_parent_id;
    END IF;

    SELECT article_date INTO date_article FROM article WHERE article_id = :NEW.comment_article_id;

    IF :NEW.comment_date > SYSTIMESTAMP THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, '...');
    ELSIF :NEW.comment_date < date_article THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, '...');
    ELSIF :NEW.comment_date < date_parent THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20006, '...');
    END IF;

END;
```

Please consider anyway that such kind of programming is considered bad practice: take a look at [Fix Oracle mutating trigger table errors](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)

Comment: Yeah, I have already found exactly the same solution maybe about 5 minutes ago. It seems it's working. Thank you.